# Robot Framework with Selenium - Click Element is not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, keyword

I'm having issues with the Click Element keyword (SeleniumLibrary) with RFWK. It's not working consistently and I cannot find the root cause of it.
The page element looks like this:

```
<div class="grid-nav-controls">
  <span class="grid-nav-link" page-index="1">1</span>
  <span class="grid-nav-separator">| 
  </span><span class="grid-nav-link" page-index="2">2</span>
  <span class="grid-nav-separator">|</span>
  <div class="grid-nav-current-page">3</div>
  <span class="grid-nav-separator">|</span>
  <span class="grid-nav-link" page-index="4">4</span>
</div>
```

I want to access span with attribute page-index='4' or text()='4' (In application those are "buttons")

I tried (after checking if the page contains the element, it is enabled and visible) scrolling to this element (which works) and then:

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  ${interval}  ${timeout}  Click Element ${locator}
Click Element  ${locator}
Click Element  ${locator}  action_chain=True
Click Element at Coordinates  ${locator}  0  0
```

I even wrote my own function using action chains:

```
@keyword("Perform Click Element")
def perform_click_element(self, element):
    self.driver = self.get_webdriver_instance()
    action = ActionChains(self.driver)
    try:
        action.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
```

And nothing works, locators I used:

```
${locator}  //span[text()='4']
${locator}  //span[@page-index='4']
```

It's not the first time I've had issues with clicking elements but changing locators worked in most cases. The worst thing is that in the log **Keyword is passed and no errors are found in every tried case**. Has anyone had a similar issue? Where to look for answers/how to debug this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a long time debugging, checking and other various experiments it came down to version mismatch.

Before running the scripts I have updated robotframework to the newest version, (which also updated robotframework-selenium library) but I left old version of selenium (3.141). Needed to only update the version!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified Robot Framework script that should work:

```perl
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${URL}  https://yourwebsite.com
${TIMEOUT}  10
${INTERVAL}  1

*** Test Cases ***
Access and Click Page Index
    Open Browser  ${URL}  Chrome
    Wait Until Page Contains Element  xpath=//span[@page-index='4']  ${TIMEOUT}
    ${element_to_click} =  Get WebElement  xpath=//span[@page-index='4']
    Scroll Element Into View  ${element_to_click}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  ${INTERVAL}  ${TIMEOUT}  Click Element  xpath=//span[@page-index='4']
    Close Browser
```

If this still doesn't work, the element might be inside an iframe or there might be some JavaScript preventing the click. In that case, you might need to switch to the iframe or use JavaScript to perform the click action.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I meant to write `page-index="4"` or `span[text()='4']`

Comment: I tried it. Nothing works. The element is indeed in the iframe but I select it during suite setup. Also clicking by javascript works but only in some cases.